# How to hidden javascript code in Blogger from inspect page element?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I am trying to hide some javascript code from inspect page element.

For example I have HTML widget as:

```
<b:section class='sidebar1' id='sidebartab1' preferred='yes'>
<b:widget id='HTML1' locked='false' title='HTML' type='HTML'>
<b:includable id='main'>
                          <!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
                          <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                            <h2 class='title'>
                              <data:title/>
                            </h2>
                          </b:if>
                          <div class='widget-content'>
                            <data:content/>
                          </div>
                          <b:include name='quickedit'/>
                        </b:includable>
</b:widget>
</b:section>
```

I have input content as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('Hello Stackoverflow');
</script>
```

The output content will appear on browser is :

```
Hello Stackoverflow
```

But I still see javascript code with "inspect element".

So how can I hidden code js in Blogger from inspect page element?

Comment: You can't hide client side code from client. Best you can do is obfuscate it, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194397/447356) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Impossible at all.

You've sent a script element to the client. The inspector is running in the same scope with the same permissions as your script.

[You can obfuscate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript) (if you really need to).

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. But i still do not understand why author of this template (http://maxxiz-mkrdezign.blogspot.com/) can get post without javascript in his code. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XgMAHc_1X4w/Uixf5SnolrI/AAAAAAAAGUI/mUrlt-I-Qqk/w865-h324-no/HTML.png

Comment: @happi what JavaScript you expect to see? It's there somewhere, just in a different place.

Comment: Actually, in blogger HTML widget, to get post as my shown picture, I need to use javascript as : <script src='/feeds/posts/default/?orderby=updated&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=sticky' type='text/javascript'/>. But i do not see anything as that code in above template.